# Evaluation of hard expression with repeated exponentiation and modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Assume we want to calculate

$$
N = z^{1998000^{100^{10}}} \pmod{10^m}
$$

where $z, m$ are known ($z$ can reach up to $10$ digits and let's assume that $m$ is around $10$).

According to similar questions, it seems that the usual method is to find a $k$ such that:

$$
z^k \equiv 1 \pmod{10^m} \tag{1}
$$

Then proceed with finding:

$$
19988000^{100^{10}} \pmod{k}
$$

For solving $(1)$, the only thing that comes to mind is Euler's generalization of Fermat's little theorem, but that carries the assumption that $\text{gcd}(z,10^m) = 1$, which is not generally known.

Can you suggest a way to solve $(1)$ and how would you proceed with finding $N$ from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suppose $\gcd(z,10^m)=1$. Then we can take $k=4\cdot 10^{m-1}$, and $19988000^{100^{10}} \pmod{k}$ is clearly $0$, so $N=1$.

Now suppose, say, that $z$ is even and not divisible by $5$. Then $N\equiv 0\pmod {2^m}$; and to compute $N\bmod 5^m$, we can take $k=4\cdot 5^{m-1}$, so $N\equiv 1\pmod{5^m}$. Now you can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find $N\pmod{10^m}$.

The case when $z$ is an odd multiple of $5$ is similar.

Comment: The case of $z$ being an even multiple of $5$ is trivial?

Comment: @Paris: yes, because then it's a multiple of $10$